# C# excel automation missing conditional formattings

Tags: c#, excel, automation

I'm trying to convert an excel file(xls format) into xlsx/xlsm file format via c# excel automation using this source code:

```
workBook.SaveAs(convertedTemplatePath, outputFormat == ExcelOutputFormat.XLSM ? Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled : Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, null, null, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, false, false, null, null, null);
```

But after conversion all conditional formattings are missing. But if I'm using an installed excel and save a xls file via "Save As" to a xlsx/xlsm file format all conditional formattings are preserved. Do you have any ideas how to preserve the conditional formattings using WorkBook.SaveAs ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. It is not the excel automation. I'm additionally using a 3rd party component which unfortunately removes the conditional formattings while editing the excel file.